# How can I create an AMAZON policy with permission to an user create another user with only permissions on S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm using this policy to a user that can create other users, but I need to restrict this user to only create users with permissions on S3, that's because, currently, he can create users with permissions on all services, like EC2 or IAM.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "sts:GetFederationToken",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Are there any samples to create that policy with the restriction for users to create other users having permission only on S3?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iam:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The result was:
"User: arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/bot is not authorized to perform: sts:GetFederationToken on resource: arn:aws:sts::000000000000:federated-user/00 (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;"